# Android Permalink parameter

Tags: android, json, url, cakephp, parameters

I have problems with listview paging. My json data comes from `cakephp` based website.

As you know cakephp pagination: `www.domain.com/index/page:2`

Android passes parameters like: `www.domain.com/index?page=2`

So how can i pass parameters to my cakephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.x you can configure Paginator component to use querystring instead of named params. Check [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters).